# Having problem in sending email through django using EmailMultiAltenatives

Tags: django

I am trying to send emails through django.
This is my order.html file:

```
<body>
    <img src="{% static 'assets/img/logo/original.jpg' %}" alt="">
    {% for order in orders1 %}
<h1>Your order number is <strong>{{order}}</strong></h1>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

This is my order.txt file:

```
{% for order in orders1 %}
Your order number is {{order}}
{% endfor %}
```

And this is my views.py:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context

def email(request):
    orders1=Order.objects.filter(id=20)
    d = { 'orders': Order.objects.filter(id=20) }

    subject, from_email, to = 'hello', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, 'vatsalj2001@gmail.com'
    text_content = get_template('emails/order.txt').render(d)
    html_content = get_template('emails/order.html').render(d)
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()

    return render(request,'emails/order.html',{'orders1':orders1})
```

The concern is that the email which is being sent only contains the subject('hello') and in the email body there shows an icon(with a cross) instead of image that I want and also no text shows up which I set in template.
Also what is the need and requirements of having a text and html file for email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some changes to your program (UnTested), this should work

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string , get_template
from django.template import Context

def email(request):
    orders1=Order.objects.filter(id=20)

    subject, from_email, to = 'hello', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, 'vatsalj2001@gmail.com'
    text_content = render_to_string('emails/order.txt',{'orders1': Order.objects.filter(id=20),})
    html_content = render_to_string('emails/order.html', {'orders1': Order.objects.filter(id=20),})
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()

    return render(request,'emails/order.html',{'orders1':orders1})
```

Match the key `orders` which you are passing to text and html files, you are passing 'orders', whereas accessing `orders1`

For rendering image in the email you have to host the image at some public URL and add that path in the email body

EDIT

Text content can be directly assigned, no need to load it from a file Or another way to add text content without creating separate file

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
```

Comment: How do I host the image at public url?

Comment: Ok it worked . Thanks.  But as asked in question what is the need of having a txt file and that too with same html?

Comment: The difference is formatting, generally txt file has plain text and HTML can have formatting + images + buttons.

Comment: Public URL can be from Amamzon S3 or one image file hosted on your website

Comment: Ok but is there a need to have the text file with exactly the same content in html file? If yes then how do we write the content of buttons in html file in text file

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: also can a fail silently be used with it?